# MVC3 RenderPartial caching across multiple pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, renderpartial

Can anyone tell me if its possible to Cache a RenderPartial across multiple pages? I have a RenderPartial for a user profile that shouldn't really ever change unless the user updates their profile. So i dont really want to go back and get his/her profile every time i load a page. I would much rather pass the partial around until im forced to update (i.e. profile update)

I looked at the [DonutHole](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/12/donut-hole-caching.aspx) example that p.haack put together, but it seems to be relevant for a single page. Can someone point me in the right direction or offer any advice? Or am i only able to cache one page at a time? thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use RenderAction instead. Example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [OutputCache(Duration = 6000, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public ActionResult Cached()
    {
        // You could return whatever you want here, even a view
        // but for the purpose of the demonstration I am simply
        // returning a dynamic string value
        return Content(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), "text/html");
    }
}
```

and inside the `Index.cshtml` and `About.cshtml` views you could include the child action:

```
<div>
    @{Html.RenderAction("Cached");}
</div>
```

and it you will get the cached version of it in both pages.

Comment: Thank you Darin. That was perfect. instead of return Content I performed return PartialView(object); as you noted in your notes.

Comment: Darin, do you know of any way to get OutputCache to use a cache profile when it's used with a partial view?

Comment: @Mark Good, no this is not supported. You may take a look at the following article which explains the problem: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=665. You could write a custom action filter to fix it.