# How to prevent firefox from adding the versioning to external javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using Asp.net MVC and I have declared a reference script in my user control like this:

**UserControl1.ascx:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/script1.js") %>"></script>
```

The main page will load user control multiple times like this:

**MainPage.aspx:**

```
<% for (var i=0; i<3; i++) { %>
   <% Html.RenderPartial("UserControl1", Model) %>
<% } %>
```

When I take a look at Firebug in Firefox, I have seen the request to that script were fired multiple times with different version number added to the end of the request like this:

```
http://localhost/MySite/Scripts/script1.js?_=1437474343981
http://localhost/MySite/Scripts/script1.js?_=1437474344046
```

I expect this script will be cached in browser after the first time but due to the fact that the unexpected version added so it does not.

Anyone know how to prevent Firefox from being added that random version number to my script?

Comment: Are you sure it is added by Firefox?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194532/mvc3-renderpartial-caching-across-multiple-pages

Comment: @alan0xd7: whatever, maybe not firefox but I want to get rid of that version number...

Comment: Tried disabling all plugins?